# Mockgoose Error: shutdown ENOTCONN

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mocha.js

This is driving me mad.

I am running some unit tests with the following set up

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import mockgoose from "mockgoose";
import chai from "chai";
import chaiAsPromised from "chai-as-promised";

import entryModel from "../entryModel";
import entrySchema from "../../../schemas/entry/entrySchema";

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

mockgoose(mongoose);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
```

And when I run via the command line them I get this.

> 1) Expected functionality "before each" hook:
>        Uncaught Error: shutdown ENOTCONN
>         at exports._errnoException (util.js:837:11)
>         at Socket.onSocketFinish (net.js:211:26)
>         at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
>         at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
>         at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:468:14)
>         at endWritable (_stream_writable.js:478:3)
>         at Socket.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:443:5)
>         at Socket.end (net.js:400:31)
>         at Socket.onend (_stream_readable.js:490:10)
>         at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
>         at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
>         at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
>         at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:893:12)
>         at doNTCallback2 (node.js:429:9)
>         at process._tickCallback (node.js:343:17)

However if I run them with `gulp-mocha` I get the same error but the tests somehow still run.

Can anyone please help me out!?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to put the line

```
mongoose.connect();
```

before the:

```
mockgoose(mongoose);
```

That solved the same problem to me.